Will the power output (4.5W?) of a standard USB-A 3.1 port cause any issues with a 7.5-watt NVMe SSD in a USB-A enclosure(RTL9210B)?
(An SSD in a USB-A to NVMe enclosure (RTL9210B bridge))
Will the power output (4.5W?) of a standard USB-A 3.1 port cause any issues with a 7.5-watt NVMe SSD in a USB-A enclosure(RTL9210B)?
Or will the RTL9210B negotiate for the appropriate power consumption?
RTL9210B: https://www.realtek.com/Product/Index?id=4075

Are you trying to pull 7.5 W from a device rated at 4.5 W? That doesn't sound wise - especially if the data is valuable.

@Transistor Will the SSD adjust its power usage on its own, or will the RTL9210B instruct it to limit speed or other parameters to manage power?

@Transistor all without affecting its reliability?

You would have to check the SSD datasheet for that. There's a big difference between something that's negotiating power delivery for charging a battery (which can be done quickly or slowly) and something like an SSD.

On second thought, it’s very common for ready-made USB storage devices (designed to be powered through a standard USB port) to become unreliable if the host port can’t provide enough power. Therefore, relying on the enclosure to regulate the SSD's power usage is probably not going to be reliable.
